# Resolving named url while using subapps in aiohttp_jinja2

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to use `aiohttp-jinja2` with `app.add_subapp()`. Unfortunately I am not able to figure out how to use `{{ url('named_url') }}` in case of subapps.

I followed the docs and now I am using it as following:

`main.py`

```
app.router.add_route('GET', '/', Index)

app.add_subapp(r'/api/v1/todo', todos_app)
app['todos_app'] = todos_app
```

`index_handler.py`

```
import aiohttp_jinja2
from aiohttp import web 

class Index(web.View):
    """Index page for the server."""

    @aiohttp_jinja2.template('index.html')
    async def get(self):
        """Return a simple page with urls."""
        todos_app = self.request.app['todos_app']
        return {
            'new_todo_url': todos_app.router['new_todo'].url_for(),
        }
```

`index.html`

```
<li class="list-group-item"><a href="{{ new_todo_url }}">New Todo</a></li>
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient/better way to achieve this, by just using `url('subapp_named_resource')` ?

Comment: Good point.
Maybe we need a new context function like `{{ url_for('todos_app', 'new_todo') }}`?

Comment: This can totally work, but I was also thinking that may be when we call `add_subapp()` the named resources on main `app` can be updated  with references to `url(todos_app.new_todo)`, representing `subapp.method` But if this second method is infeasible, context function should totally work.
Should I open an issue on `aiohttp_jinja2` as well ?

Comment: Merging named resources from subapp into main app is too cumbersome.
Please open an issue. Maybe you are a champion for Pull Request too?